# Conversion of array string to array ulong in c#

Tags: c#, explicit-conversion

I have a array of strings having values

```
string[] words = {"0B", "00", " 00",  "00",  "00", "07",  "3F",  "14", "1D"};
```

I need it to convert into array of ulong

```
ulong[] words1;
```

How should I do it in c#
I think I should add some background.
The data in the string is coming from textbox and I need to write the content of this textbox in the hexUpDown.Value parameter.

Comment: What have you tried? Just google for "convert string to ulong" and then repeat that for every element in your array.

Comment: ulong words1 = Convert.ToUInt64(words[1]);
Have tried it, but when I execute it I get a error saying  "Input string not in correct format"

Comment: And try to learn LINQ as soon as possible, it'll make things like this much easier.

Comment: @SoptikHa That´s a really bad suggestion and makes programmers over-use LINQ as "magic tool to make everything easier", while that often leads to harder to read code. In particular if you don´t know the basics behind, which is good old-style looping.

Comment: ulong[] words1 = words.Select(ulong.Parse).ToArray();
I did try this as well, but it gives me the same error.
I need to put this value in a hexUpDown.Value which is a part of my design layout

Comment: `NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` is your friend.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know it can be harder to read, but isn't this a problem that could be (and should be) solved with linq easily? I'm not professional, but I love when I can use LINQ instead of multiple for loops. I personally think LINQ is even more readable than loops with more complex arrays and objects. When I was learning LINQ, I used these simple problems to practice, which helped me a lot when I encountered complex collections later. This experience led me to suggest him to learn it on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ulongs = words.Select(x => ulong.Parse(x, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to combine the bytes into 64 bit values then try this (assumes correct endieness).

```cs
string[] words = { "0B", "00", " 00", "00", "00", "07", "3F", "14", "1D" };
var words64 = new List<string>();
int wc = 0;
var s = string.Empty;
var results = new List<ulong>();

// Concat string to make 64 bit words
foreach (var word in words) 
{
    // remove extra whitespace
    s += word.Trim();
    wc++;

    // Added the word when it's 64 bits
    if (wc % 4 == 0)
    {
        words64.Add(s);
        wc = 0;
        s = string.Empty;
    }
}

// If there are any leftover bits, append those
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
    words64.Add(s);
}

// Now attempt to convert each string to a ulong
foreach (var word in words64)
{
    ulong r;
    if (ulong.TryParse(word, 
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        out r))
    {
        results.Add(r);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
List<ulong>(3) { 184549376, 474900, 29 }
```

Comment: Alternatively, I might prefer `for (int i=0; i < (items.Count / 4) + 1; i++) { words64.Add(string.Join(string.Empty, items.Skip(i*4).Take(4))); }`

Comment: ulong words1 = Convert.ToUInt64(words[1],16);
This Simply worked for me than any other solutions, bur thanks anyway.